# Is there a formal, rigorous definition of cellular automata?

Tags: definition, cellular-automata

I have recently been interested in cellular automata. However, I have never seen a formal definition of them. Is there one, and if so, what is the definition?

Comment: Where have you looked?

Comment: You can find a very general definition on Wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automata_theory#Formal_definition

Comment: Look at the book by [S. Wolfram](https://www.stephenwolfram.com/publications/cellular-automata-complexity/)